# How to compare two lists

Tags: c#, list

I have a list for answer that received from users like below:

```
List<UserAnswerToQue> lstGetUserAnswerIndex = new List<UserAnswerToQue>();
```

and class UserAnswerToQue is like below:

```
public class UserAnswerToQue
{
    int _Qu_Id;
    string _Title;

    public UserAnswerToQue(int qu_Id, string ans_Title)
    {
        _Qu_Id = qu_Id;
        _Title = ans_Title;
    }
 }
```

and have a list for true answer to the question:

```
var ListFinalTrueAnswer = (from x in FilteredTrueReceivedAnswerList
                                       select (x.qu_Id, x.ans_Title)).ToList();
```

The list ListFinalTrueAnswer contains Item1 and Item2

I want to find true answer that user gave to the questions and for that I need to compare two list lstGetUserAnswerIndex and ListFinalTrueAnswer.
How to compare this two list and fine which answers is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var userTrueAnswer = lstGetUserAnswerIndex.Where(w=> ListFinalTrueAnswer.Any(a=>a.qu_Id == w.qu_Id && a.ans_Title == w.ans_Title));
```

Comment: When I use your code i have error in ( w.qu_Id and w.ans_Title ). Error is the list does not contain a defination for qu_Id

Comment: maybe you field a little bit differ from  w.qu_Id and w.ans_Title. Maybe w._Qu_Id and  w._Title?

Comment: No, It desn't retrieve any field

Comment: Because you field is private!!!Change it and feild wll become is available

Answer (score 3):

Create a hashset with the IDs of the true answer questions. (To get fast lookup)

```
var trueAnswers = ListFinalTrueAnswer.Select(x => (x.qu_Id, x.ans_Title)).ToHashSet();
```

Than filter your list using the hashset,

```
var userAnswers = lstGetUserAnswerIndex.Where(x => trueAnswers.Contains((x._Qu_Id, x._Title)));
```

Comment: how it work? if got it right you getting hash by quastionId, not by answerId

Comment: @evilGenius There is no answerId anywhere that I can see.

Comment: me too) So it's wierd)

Comment: @Magnus I need to compare two filds qu_Id and ans_Title  from two list with each orher. one field comparing doesn't resolve my problem.

Comment: @O.Ahmadpoor In that case use a value tuple with the two properties. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Magnus My C# project dosn't have a defination for ToHashSet()

Comment: @O.Ahmadpoor Perhaps you are using an older version of the framework? ToHashSet is defined: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tohashset But you can also do: `new HashSet<(int, string)>(ListFinalTrueAnswer.Select(x => (x.qu_Id, x.ans_Title)));`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, we can add public getters to our class. It's a better way to make fields private and access their values by public getters:

```
public class UserAnswerToQue 
{
    // ...
    public int Qu_Id => this._Qu_Id;
    public string Title => this._Title;
    // ...
}
```

Our dummy input list of answers:

```
List<UserAnswerToQue> lstGetUserAnswerIndex = new List<UserAnswerToQue>() {
    new UserAnswerToQue(1, "Water"),
    new UserAnswerToQue(2, "Metal"),
};
```

Your `ListFinalTrueAnswer` in second block of code is actually a List of tuples. This can be determined here:

```
select (x.qu_Id, x.ans_Title)
```

So, let us have a dummy list, that represents your list of tuples:

```
var ListFinalTrueAnswer = new List<Tuple<int, string>>() {
    new Tuple<int, string> (1, "Water"),
    new Tuple<int, string> (2, "Wood"),
};
```

Now we can check our dummy input list of answers:

```
lstGetUserAnswerIndex.Where(x => ListFinalTrueAnswer.Contains(new Tuple<int, string>(x.Qu_Id, x.Title)))
```

This kinda rich operation, so we can rewrite our query a little:

```
var ListFinalTrueAnswer2 = from x in FilteredTrueReceivedAnswerList select new { x.qu_Id, x.ans_Title }
```

We now have an `IEnumerable` of anonymous classes. And our list comparing:

```
lstGetUserAnswerIndex.Where(x => ListFinalTrueAnswer2.Any(y => (y.qu_Id == x.Qu_Id) && (y.ans_Title == x.Title)))
```